# Can we insert user defined types in HashMap as Key and Value?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, key

How can we insert user defined types in HashMap as Key and Value?

```
HashMap<key, value>
```

Key as user defined.
Value also as user defined.

Comment: yes.. you can insert any *Object* into the `HashMap`

Comment: simply use `Map<Object,Object>`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Note that you should *consider* overriding equals and hashCode to implement custom equality.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but the key must have properly overridden `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods for it to work correctly.

Comment: That depends on what "work correctly" means. If you're happy with equality based on reference identity (which is often fine) you don't need to override anything.

Comment: @JonSkeet Then you'd probably want to use `IdentityHashMap` to convey that particular intent.

Comment: @Kayaman: Not necessarily. I'd normally use that to convey "I don't want to use the normal meaning of equality that this type provides." And don't forget that the person creating the type and the person creating the map may well be different...